# How to install older GNURadio on Windows using WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to install GNURadio on Win 11 using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I need to install an older version of GNURadio (3.8), but at the end of the procedure version 10.1.1 gets installed.

I first execute the commands from https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=UnInstallGR#From_PPA to remove any gnuradio I might have.

Then, following the wiki https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=LinuxInstall#Ubuntu_PPA_Installation,

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases-3.8
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install gnuradio
```

but I get version 3.10. Why is that?
Thank you